# Return multiple vars inside loop PHP

Tags: php, loops, pdo, return, echo

I want to return multiple notifications within a `loop`. I have 2 functions, the first one which pulls the notifications from the database and the second one for the dashboard header. The dashboard header is where the notifications will be displayed.

Now, the issue is, for some reason only one notification will be displayed. I've tried changing the `return` inside the `loop` to `echo` but that outputs the notifications at the beginning of `dashboardTop()`.

What's going wrong and how can I resolve this?

```
public function loopNotifications() {
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM notification WHERE isto=:user_id");
    $stmt->execute(array(':user_id'=>$_SESSION['user_id']));

    while ($notification = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $from = $this->pullName($notification['isto']);
        return '<li><a href="javascript:;">' . $notification['content'] . '</a></li>';
    }
}

public function dashboardTop() {
    echo '
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                <i class="material-icons">notifications</i>
                                <span class="notification">' . $this->notificationCount() . '</span>
                                <p class="hidden-lg hidden-md">Notifications</p>
                            </a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                ' . $this->loopNotifications() . '
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="index.php?page=profile" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                               <i class="material-icons">person</i>
                               <p class="hidden-lg hidden-md">Profile</p>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
    ';
}
```

Comment: you can not....

Comment: you should pass the "notifications" as a parameter to `dashboardTop()` and then loop through them

Comment: `return` ends execution so no matter how many lines there are, you will only ever get one. concatenate, in to a string,  then return that

Comment: `loopNotifications()` returns straight away after the first iteration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public function loopNotifications() {
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM notification WHERE isto=:user_id");
    $stmt->execute(array(':user_id'=>$_SESSION['user_id']));
    $out=''; //empty var tof concaternation
    while ($notification = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $from = $this->pullName($notification['isto']);
        $out.= '<li><a href="javascript:;">' . $notification['content'] . '</a></li>'; //concaternate each line in to string
    }
return $out; //return whole string
}

public function dashboardTop() {
    echo '
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                <i class="material-icons">notifications</i>
                                <span class="notification">' . $this->notificationCount() . '</span>
                                <p class="hidden-lg hidden-md">Notifications</p>
                            </a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                ' . $this->loopNotifications() . '
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="index.php?page=profile" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                               <i class="material-icons">person</i>
                               <p class="hidden-lg hidden-md">Profile</p>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
    ';
}
```